# Can Search Engine read robots.txt if it's read access is restricted?

Tags: .htaccess, seo, robots.txt, google-crawlers

I have added robots.txt file and added some lines to restrict some folders.Also i added restriction from all to access that robots.txt file using .htaccess file.Can Search engines read content of that file?

Answer (score 1):

This file should be freely readable. Search engine are like visitors on your website. If a visitor can't see this file, then the search engine will not be able to see it either.

There's absolutely no reason to try to hide this file.

Answer (score 1):

Web crawlers need to be able to HTTP GET your robots.txt, or they will be unable to parse the file and respect your configuration.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no! But the simplest and safest too, is still to try:
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062598?hl=en

> The robots.txt Tester tool shows you whether your robots.txt file
>   blocks Google web crawlers from specific URLs on your site. For
>   example, you can use this tool to test whether the Googlebot-Image
>   crawler can crawl the URL of an image you wish to block from Google
>   Image Search.

Comment: I have restricted my admin access folder from all ip's except my ip in htaccess and added Disallow to that folder in robots file also..then what will happen?